# create individual variables of the foreach array to put in mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, foreach

I want to create individual variables of an array in foreach (arrays are obtained from the database, in the database there are 2017,2018,2019,2020 years value), selected through jquery, but every time I choose the year before, the result is 2020.

```
$tahun = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT year(log) FROM data_sensor WHERE log GROUP BY year(log)");

$tahuns = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tahun)) {
    $tahuns[] = $row;
}

<script>
<?php foreach($tahuns as $row){  ?>
        $(".year<?php echo $row[0]; ?>").click(function(){
        <?php $choosen_year= $row[0]; ?> //declare choosen year
        ....
        });
<?php } ?>
</script>

<?php

$bulan = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT month(log) FROM data_sensor WHERE year(log) = '$choosen_year' GROUP BY month(log)");
$Bulan = mysqli_fetch_array($bulan);

echo $Bulan; //result always 2020

?>
```

I want the selected array to be the same as the one shown. Thanks for response

Comment: $(".year"+<?php echo $row[0]; ?>+) use this way

Comment: Php is not jquery. You can't use a jquery function to assign a php variable. You would need to completely refactor your approach to use ajax to dynamically update the data.